# ffmpeg: use vidstabtransform to overlay it over blurred background

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I am using `ffmpeg` to concatenate multiple video clips taken from the same object over multiple timeframes. To make sure the videos are properly aligned (and therefore show the object in rougly the same position), I manually identify two points in the first frame each clip, and use that to calculate the scaling and positioning necessary for proper alignment. I'm using Python for this, and it also generates the ffmpeg command for me. When it has calculated that the appropriate scale of the video is less than 100%, that means that some parts of the frame will become black. To counter that, I overlay the scaled and positioned video over a blurred version of the original video (like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJpPV.png) effect)

Now, additionally, some of the video clips are a bit shaky, so my flow now first applies the `vidstabdetect` and `vidstabtransform` filters, and uses the transformed stabilized version as input for my final command. However, if the shaking is significant, the `vidstabtransform` will zoom in and therefore I will either lose some of the details around the edges, or a black border is created around the edge. As I am later including the stabilized version of the video in the concatenation, with the possibility of it shrinking, I would rather perform the `vidstabtransform` step inside my command, and use the output directly into the overlay over the blurred version. That way, I would want to achieve that the clip rotates across the frame as it is stabilized, and it is shown over the blurred background. Is it possible to achieve this using ffmpeg, or am I trying to stretch it too far?

As a minimal example, these are my commands:

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -vf vidstabdetect=output=transform.trf -f null - 

ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -vf vidstabtransform=input=transform.trf video1_stabilized.mp4

# same for video2.mp4

ffmpeg -i video1_stabilized.mp4 -i video2_stabilized.mp4 -filter_complex "
    [0:v]split=2[v0blur][v0scale];
    [v0blur]gblur=sigma=50[v0blur];  // blur the video
    [v0scale]scale=round(iw*0.8/2)*2:round(ih*0.8/2)*2[v0scale];  // scale the video
    [v0blur][v0scale]overlay=x=100:y=200[v0];  // overlay the scaled video over the blur at a specific location
    [1:v]split=2[v1blur][v1scale];
    [v1blur]gblur=sigma=50[v1blur];
    [v1scale]scale=round(iw*0.9/2)*2:round(ih*0.9/2)*2[v1scale];
    [v1blur][v1scale]overlay=x=150:y=150[v1];
    [v0][v1]concat=n=2  // concatenate the two clips" 
-c:v libx264 -r 30 out.mp4
```

So, I know I can put the `vidstabtransform` step into the `filter_complex`-graph (I'll do the detection in a separate step still), but can I also use it such that I can achieve the stabilization over the blurred background and have the clip move around the frame as it is stabilized?

EDIT: so to include `vidstabtransform` into the filter graph, it would then look like this:

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -filter_complex "
    [0:v]vidstabtransform=input=transform1.trf[v0stab]
    [v0stab]split=2[v0blur][v0scale];
    ...
    [1:v]vidstabtransform=input=transform2.trf[v1stab]
    [v1stab]split=2[v1blur][v1scale];
    ...
    [v0][v1]concat=n=2"
-c:v libx264 -r 30 out.mp4
```